# About factorial in newlisp

Tags: ecl, newlisp

I run facorial function using ECL and newlisp.

ECL:

```
>(defun fac (n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (fac (- n 1)))))
>(fac 20)
22432902008176640000
>(fac 30)
2265252859812191058636308480000000
>(fac 40)
815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000
...
```

newlisp

```
>(define (fac n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (fac (- n 1)))))
>(fac 20)
22432902008176640000
>(fac 30)
-8764578968847253504
```

Why does newlisp return different result with ecl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newLISP is designed to be small (~260K), and one of the things you won't get by default is support for really big integers, and the necessary automatic conversion between ordinary-sized and big integers. If you regularly need integers such as 1000! in your work, then you've probably chosen the wrong language. However, if you want to use newLISP for other reasons, and really really need to calculate 100!, then install the GMP library, and write your code as follows:

```
(load "gmp.lsp")
(define (factorial-gmp num)
 (if (= num 0)
  "1"
  (GMP:* (string num) (factorial-gmp (- num 1)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Largest 64-bit  integer in newLISP is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 2):

try floating point:

```
(define (fac n) (if (= n 1) 1 (mul n (fac (sub n 1)))))

(fac 20) => 2.432902008e+18
```

Comment: (fac 100) => 9.332621544e+157,  that's great !  However, newlisp cannot calculate (fac 1000) but ECL does !

Comment: BTW, why the `+ - * /` isnot polymorphic as CL does ?

Comment: The manual tells you how to define these operators so that they work with imprecise FP numbers as well as precise integers... :)

Answer (score 2):

Since version 10.4.8 newLISP has built-in support (bigint) for unlimited precision integers. This makes the GNU GMP module gmp.lsp obsolete. But due to the way bigint works, you'll see a totally different factorial function than the typical recursive one:

```
(define (fac n) (apply * (map bigint (sequence 1 n)) 2))
(fac 1000)

> 
(lambda (n) (apply * (map bigint (sequence 1 n)) 2))
402387260077093773543702433923003985719374864210714632543799910429938512398629020592044208486969404800479988610197196058631666872994808558901323829669944590997424504087073759918823627727188732519779505950995276120874975462497043601418278094646496291056393887437886487337119181045825783647849977012476632889835955735432513185323958463075557409114262417474349347553428646576611667797396668820291207379143853719588249808126867838374559731746136085379534524221586593201928090878297308431392844403281231558611036976801357304216168747609675871348312025478589320767169132448426236131412508780208000261683151027341827977704784635868170164365024153691398281264810213092761244896359928705114964975419909342221566832572080821333186116811553615836546984046708975602900950537616475847728421889679646244945160765353408198901385442487984959953319101723355556602139450399736280750137837615307127761926849034352625200015888535147331611702103968175921510907788019393178114194545257223865541461062892187960223838971476088506276862967146674697562911234082439208160153780889893964518263243671616762179168909779911903754031274622289988005195444414282012187361745992642956581746628302955570299024324153181617210465832036786906117260158783520751516284225540265170483304226143974286933061690897968482590125458327168226458066526769958652682272807075781391858178889652208164348344825993266043367660176999612831860788386150279465955131156552036093988180612138558600301435694527224206344631797460594682573103790084024432438465657245014402821885252470935190620929023136493273497565513958720559654228749774011413346962715422845862377387538230483865688976461927383814900140767310446640259899490222221765904339901886018566526485061799702356193897017860040811889729918311021171229845901641921068884387121855646124960798722908519296819372388642614839657382291123125024186649353143970137428531926649875337218940694281434118520158014123344828015051399694290153483077644569099073152433278288269864602789864321139083506217095002597389863554277196742822248757586765752344220207573630569498825087968928162753848863396909959826280956121450994871701244516461260379029309120889086942028510640182154399457156805941872748998094254742173582401063677404595741785160829230135358081840096996372524230560855903700624271243416909004153690105933983835777939410970027753472000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 10.4.8 newLISP has built-in support (bigint) for unlimited precision integers.

bigint recursive factorial:

```
> (define (fac n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* (bigint n) (fac (- n 1)))))
> (fac 20)
2432902008176640000L
> (fac 30)
265252859812191058636308480000000L
> (fac 40)
815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000L
```